# Microsoft Reporting v.10 load problem

Tags: web-config, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to reference microsoft reporting v.10.0.0.0 in my vs studio web site. For some reason it can't achieve that as it is always giving me a compile error that it could not load the type.

Error 2625 Could not load type 'Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

One thing that I think it might be a cause is that I had moved from 9.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 and after that it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

After replacing all ofthe references from version 8 or 9 to 10 (in webconfig and also in your asp.net pages. In web.Config file you have to change the following line from

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

to

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

**Update**

You also have to update all of the other reference Number from 9.0.0 to 10.0.0

Answer (score 7):

RdlBuildProvider has been moved to Webforms in version 10, which used to be in common earlier

Comment: Excellent catch. This resolved the last of my issues.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to provide a complete answer.

Notice that the key token is the same for v8 and v10.  Also, as Madhu said, note that **Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider** has been moved from **Common** to **Webforms** as shown in the *buildProviders* section.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
</assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Webforms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</buildProviders>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/8287e1cd-767e-463c-8cb0-60c275fe5ed6