# ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?

Tags: windows-7, reportviewer, internet-explorer-10

I have been searching for the answer for this for 2 days. We have an application that uses ReportViewer 9. However, clicking on the print button in IE10 causes the browser to stop working (with the "Debug" or "Close Program" buttons). Everything else seems to work fine.

We tried using ReportViewer 10 but we get the same issue.

We are using Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7, IE 10, and targeting .NET 4.0. The crashes happen in the IDE and through IIS.

---

#### EDIT: Things I Have Tried:

1. I have tried adding my website to Trusted Sites, lowered the security setting, and I think I've tried every possible combination of checkboxes in the "custom" security box.
2. I've tried enabling Protected Mode and Enhanced Protected Mode, with a variety of check box combinations from Custom security level that sounded promising.
3. I've tried forcing IE10 to run in 64-bit mode (including the tabs), but our app forces the tab to run in 32-bit anyway.
4. Someone suggested that it might be a Kill Bit issue, so I tried editing the registry to ignore kill bits just to see if it would work (it didn't).
5. Also, I'm pretty sure I've tried just about every permutation of all the variables I've already mentioned. (I'm a little burnt out at this point, so I might have missed 1 :S)
6. [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/c7ae552d-dded-4b02-a5b9-93f6eea39258/) seemed promising but I could not get it to work. It is talking about Win8 but I thought I might be able to apply them to my situation.
7. [I found a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149492/microsoft-reporting-v-10-load-problem) changing the BuildProvider assembly to `type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WEBFORMS ..."` (instead of Common), but so far that is not working either.
8. Tried installing Report Viewer 11, and installing a very old version of our application. Both give me the same result.

Comment: Some additional things I did today: tried installing Report Viewer 11 and installing a very old version of our application. Both give me the same result.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aha! OK, so it turns out that my issue is NOT with ReportViewer, but rather with RSClientPrint. Once I did a google search for that I quickly found that the answer is: Upgrade to Sql Server 2008 R2 SERVICE PACK 2.

The version of RsClientPrint you get with R2/SP2 is 10.50.4000, while the version I had was 10.50.1600.

In conclusion, it appears that RSClientPrint 10.50.1600 is NOT COMPATIBLE with IE10, but version 10.50.4000 IS.

I REALLY hope this helps someone else!!