# Internet Explorer 10 Display Issue for SSRS report

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, internet-explorer-10

[image]

We have implemented SSRS report in our web application and everything is working great with all browsers and all thier versions, except when one specific user was navigated between the screens when suddenly the SSRS frame got minimized like you can see in the image above. It used to be spread widely on the screen but now it looks like this.

we tried deleting cookies and cache and restarting the computer. didn't work.
is there anything else we could try?

Comment: Have you tried viewing in compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes, also tried the Developer tool to view it in different browser mode.. didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your SQL server is up-to-date (you did not mention your sql version, so i am going to assume that you are 2008 R2). There are several SSRS issues on ie 10+ that are resolved with upgrading SQL Server 2008 R2 to service pack 2. 
[ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10)

You can get 2008 R2 SP2 here
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

It finally got fixed, after uninstall Internet Explorer 10 last update.

thanks!

Comment: That's not a solution, that's your way of avoiding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post on an old(ish) thread, but I fixed this recently.
Press F12 (or alt, then Tools then Developer Tools) in Internet Explorer and change the document mode from Quirks to Standard.

OR even Alt-S and Alt-Q to toggle between!

Comment: Also recently noticed that adding the site to compatibility view helps to sort this permanently.