# Print button not available in ReportViewer using IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, reportviewer, internet-explorer-11

So we noticed that the print button in our ReportViewer (`Version=10.0.0.0`) is gone after upgrading to `IE11`.
This is how it looks like in `IE10`:
[image]
After doing some research, we found that other people are also reporting this problem (i.e. [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3084f863-01c3-4593-875f-24632fa13852/internet-explorer-11-ssrs-reportviewer?forum=ieextensiondevelopment)), but did not find a solution yet.
Using the compability mode would be a workaround option, but is not a viable/fitting solution for clients.
Did anyone figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These weeks ,we face the same problem.
Finally we find some way to solve it, here is steps:

1. update "Report Viewer 2012 Runtime" to 11.1.3366
2. update "Microsoft .Net Framework" to 4.5.1
3. reboot system

Our environment:
Win server 2008 r2,
IIS7,
ReportViewer 11

Answer (score 1):

I have used code from that page(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx) and created a class for that. You can add a button to page and call it.

```
---- Call ---------
ReportPrinter prnt = new ReportPrinter();
prnt.Print(rpt.LocalReport);

Class Code
------------    
    using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace javaFish.blogspot.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prints report as xps file to default printer.
    /// </summary>
    public class ReportPrinter : IDisposable
    {
        //Local variables
        private int m_currentPageIndex;
        private IList<Stream> m_streams;
        private LocalReport report = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to save an image for each page of the report.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <param name="fileNameExtension"></param>
        /// <param name="encoding"></param>
        /// <param name="mimeType"></param>
        /// <param name="willSeek"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>    
        private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_streams.Add(stream);
            return stream;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="report"></param>
        private void Export()
        {
            string deviceInfo =
              @"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>"+ report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize.Width.ToString()+ @"in</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>" + report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize.Height.ToString() + @"in</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>" + report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins.Top.ToString() + @"in</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>" + report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins.Left.ToString() + @"in</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>" + report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins.Right.ToString() + @"in</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>" + report.GetDefaultPageSettings().Margins.Bottom.ToString() + @"in</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
               out warnings);
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Position = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handler for PrintPageEvents
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="ev"></param>
        private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            Metafile pageImage = new
               Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

            // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                ev.PageBounds.Width,
                ev.PageBounds.Height);

            // Draw a white background for the report
            ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            // Draw the report content
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

            // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
            m_currentPageIndex++;
            ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exports local report and tries to print
        /// </summary>
        public bool Print(LocalReport localReport)
        {
            try
            {
                report = localReport;
                Export();

                if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
                    throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
                PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
                if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
                }
                else
                {
                    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
                    m_currentPageIndex = 0;
                    printDoc.Print();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose resources
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (m_streams != null)
            {
                foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                    stream.Close();
                m_streams = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it seems like a good solution. I am just having 1 issue implementing it.  Have you had any issues with the code not finding a "Default Printer Settings"? ``  if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
            }`` This statement is throwing a exception for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to your SQL server is upgraded to Service Pack 2. There are several issues compatibility issues with ie10+ and SQL Server 2008R2 RTM.

[ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10)

```
The following table lists the major releases of SQL Server 2008 R2.
Release Product version
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2   10.50.4000.0
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1   10.50.2500.0
SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM  10.50.1600.1
```

[Microsoft Article on Server Version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:

```
Select @@version
```

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me so much.

[http://www.msigman.com/ssrs-print-icon-not-appearing-in-internet-explorer-11-not-able-to-print-reports-from-ie11/][1]

2 way to solve this issue was introduced:

1- install .Net 4.5.1
[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773][1]

OR
2- Add a browser file as the above source says:

> create a new Browser file in the App_Browsers folder in the root of
>   your solution.  Paste the following text in the file and then run. 
>   The issue should be solved.

```js
<browsers>
<browser id="IE11Preview" parentID="Mozilla">
<identification>
<userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+).*rv:(?'revision'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?))" />
<userAgent nonMatch="MSIE" />
<userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
</identification>
<capabilities>
<capability name="browser" value="IE" />
<capability name="layoutEngine" value="Trident" />
<capability name="layoutEngineVersion" value="${layoutVersion}" />
<capability name="extra" value="${extra}" />
<capability name="isColor" value="true" />
<capability name="majorversion" value="${major}" />
<capability name="minorversion" value="${minor}" />
<capability name="screenBitDepth" value="8" />
<capability name="type" value="IE${major}" />
<capability name="version" value="${version}" />
<capability name="isColor" value="true" />
<capability name="screenBitDepth" value="8" />
<capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
<capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
<capability name="javascript" value="true" />
<capability name="javascriptversion" value="1.5" />
<capability name="w3cdomversion" value="1.0" />
<capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
<capability name="activexcontrols" value="true" />
<capability name="backgroundsounds" value="true" />
<capability name="cookies" value="true" />
<capability name="frames" value="true" />
<capability name="javaapplets" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsCallback" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsFileUpload" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsVCard" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsXmlHttp" value="true" />
<capability name="tables" value="true" />
<capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute" value="true" />
<capability name="preferredRenderingType" value="html5" />
<capability name="tagwriter" value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
<capability name="vbscript" value="true" />
</capabilities>
</browser>
</browsers>
```

If the problem is already exists, set the ***`compatibility view setting`*** of **`IE11`**.