# Report Viewer Print Button in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reportviewer, internet-explorer-11

I am using Report Viewer to remotely generate reports and I wish to have the print control button in the report header using IE 11.

This question is similar to the following:

[Print button not available in ReportViewer using IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093371/print-button-not-available-in-reportviewer-using-ie11)

I have not been able to solve this issue. I have upgraded Report Viewer 2012 Runtime to 11.1.3452.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2 to SP2.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and .NET framework 4.5.1 on the server. IIS is version 7.

I can see print buttons in all previous versions of IE (10,9,8,....)

I've also tried forcing the user agent to IE10 using this line:
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"

According to the answers to the above question, I should have the print button. Any other suggestions besides compatibility mode or creating my own print button?

Comment: If it isn't displaying it, I would use Chrome's developer toolbars and see if the HTML element is there and set to "display: none;" or  if it's just not generated due to compatibility issues. On the other hand, creating your own print button and having a JavaScript print button will not print the pages correctly, it will just print the HTML that is rendered on to your page.

Comment: When using the Reports Manager from SQL in IE11, do you have the print and zoom buttons?

Comment: We have a working printer button, but no zoom button.  Note that the below answer was not used as a fix.  Another member of the project team ended up fixing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ReportViewer client printing feature relies on **ActiveX** which is not
>   supported by any browser except **IE 9 (or earlier)**, that's why you do
>   not get print button when Chrome, Firefox or IE10/11 browser is
>   involved. For printing, you should export to PDF and let the user to
>   print it.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1962293.aspx?+Report+Viewer+print+Button+missing+from+browser

Answer (score 0):

IE needs an add-on, `RSClient`, for the print button to work. Normally, the first time a user loads a report on IE, you'll see a prompt to download and install the add-on. Unfortunately, a lot of things can interfere with this. I'm not sure this will help you, but security settings were an issue for us.

Try this:

1. Remove the `RSClientPrint` add-on if it's installed. (Open the Control Panel, Internet Properties. Click the *Programs* tab and *Manage Add-Ons*.)
2. Click the *Security* tab, select the *Trusted Sites* zone, and then click the *Sites* button.
3. Add your web site to the zone and save your changes.

Open IE and navigate to your web site and the report. Hopefully, you'll see the prompt to download and install `RSClientPrint` and everything will work well. If it doesn't try to download, I would focus on the server.