# Internet Explorer 11 SSRS Reports Integrated with SharePoint - Print Option missing

Tags: sharepoint-2010, meta-tags, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, ssrs-2008-r2

We have a problem with our SharePoint 2010 site that has SSRS 2008 R2 Integrated reports.  When viewing the Actions menu, the Print option is missing.

This may seem like an easy answer... Put it in Compatibility Mode.  This would work, HOWEVER, we have a custom .NET app that does NOT work with Compatibility mode turned on.  I have no control over it, I just have to work around it...

So, I was able to resolve other IE 11 compatibility issues like InfoPath forms crashing out by adjusting the master page and making the compatibility mode set to 9 in a meta tag.  I added the same meta tag to the RSViewerPage.aspx page with no luck.

Is there anyone out there that may have an idea on how to get around this issue?  Many of our outside users have upgraded to Windows 8.1 and cannot go back to an earlier version of IE.

Comment: Clever....  We will be upgrading later next year...  Serious answers please...

Comment: Kinda' was serious. Maybe look at an SP2013 site and see how _it_ handles IE11, then make the same changes? Set one up real quick on Azure?

Comment: We have similar issues with SSRS 2012 SP1.  Would really like a Microsoft-ratified fix other than simply dumbing IE11 down.  It is their browser and their report server, after all.

Comment: I completely agree.   So far our fix is to have our users use Firefox.  It's pretty disappointing that I can't get my Microsoft Products to play nicely together.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is SQL Server R2 without SP2. I had to upgrade to Sql Server 2008 R2 SERVICE PACK 2.

> The version of RsClientPrint you get with R2/SP2 is 10.50.4000, while
>   the version I had was 10.50.1600.

[ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10)

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with our Sharepoint site and IE - even using Compatibility not always helping.

What I found out is something related to User Authentication not picking up.

To work around this - I was clicking on the Site logo to redo the process of authentication and that was always doing the trick.

Is this happening with all the site users?