# Reporting Services report hangs in Internet Explorer only

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS2008R2 report that runs just fine through Chrome and Firefox but will not run at all in Internet Explorer.  I have tried IE9, IE10, and IE11 but I get the same results. I just get the green 'Loading' circle but the report never opens.  I can run exactly the same report with the same parameters in Chrome and Firefox and it returns within about 2 seconds.  This is a multi-page report with page breaks set.  Other than that, I cannot think of anything unusual about the report.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same issue with IE10 and IE11 (don't know about IE9) and if I put the browser in compatibility mode the report ran fine.

Here's how to put IE10 into compatibility mode http://techathlon.com/internet-explorer-10-run-compatibility-mode/

**Update**

This issue can also be fixed by upgrading to the Reporting Services that comes with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  We were planning on migrating to MSSQL2012/SSRS2012 in the near future.  Looks like the future needs to be nearer than planned for.

Comment: I had to take IE9 OUT of compatibility mode in order to get the report to work.  But then I have to put IE IN compatibility mode in order to access any of the report management options.  Nice work, Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to make sure to your SQL server is upgraded to Service Pack 2. There are several issues compatibility issues with ie10+ and SQL Server 2008R2 RTM.

[ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10)

```
The following table lists the major releases of SQL Server 2008 R2.
Release Product version
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2   10.50.4000.0
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1   10.50.2500.0
SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM  10.50.1600.1
```

[Microsoft Article on Server Version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:

```
Select @@version
```

Comment: The SQL Server servers in question are already at version 10.50.4000.0 (SP2).  Also, the report runs fine when running IE in compatibility mode.  However, the site that it is running on cannot be run in compatibility mode as that mode is incompatible with other parts of the site.

Answer (score 0):

For IE11, add the report server to the compatibility view list.

Alt-key>Tools>Compatibility View Settings>"Add this website:"(the SSRS website should already be listed)>Add.  Select "Display intranet sites in compatibility view" > Close.