# SSRS Report stucks at loading IE 11

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, reportmanager

We are running SQL Server 2008 R2.  All these reports were working fine until we upgraded IE from 10 to 11. Every time we run a report, it will just stuck at loading forever.

Tried changing the document mode to other versions.

Comment: Anything in the server event log? Javascript console of the browser?

Comment: Does it load under compatibility mode?

Comment: Set your browser to backward compatible see what happen then ??

Comment: It works when I add the site to Compatibility View.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, and found a more detailed question and potential answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21993721/419956

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the OP, add the site to Compatibility View.

It's also possible that the browser detection needs to be updated on the server side for .Net [per this blog article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx). Basically, [there's a hotfix for ASP.Net 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088) and [one for ASP.Net 3.5sp1 and ASP.net 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565) that you need to apply. Alternatively, you can update to ASP.Net 4.5 which will also fix the 4.0 issue.

Comment: @user3268139 Did the additional information about that browser detection issue help at all? (You'll need to remove that site from the compatibility list to see if it really worked.)

Comment: I installed this patch and it seemed to fix the issue, but then next day it was broken again :|

Answer (score 1):

You might need to upgrade to your SQL server to Service Pack 2. There are several issues compatibility issues with ie10+ and SQL Server 2008R2 RTM.

[ReportViewer's Print Button Incompatible with IE 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10)

```
The following table lists the major releases of SQL Server 2008 R2.
Release Product version
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2   10.50.4000.0
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1   10.50.2500.0
SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM  10.50.1600.1
```

[Microsoft Article on Server Version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:

```
Select @@version
```

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes just restarting the reporting services (Services) might also help, just like in my case ;)